# What's the different between Vector2.Transform() and Vector2.TransformNormal() in XNA(C#)

Tags: c#, xna, game-engine, game-physics

I am developing a game in XNA (C#), I am wondering how to use 2 versions of transformation. In my idea, the works of this functions are:

(Assume that vectors are originated from `Matrix.Identity`)

- `Vector2 resultVec = Vector2.Transform(sourceVector, destinationMatrix);` is used for **Position vectors** transformation.
- `Vector2 resultVec = Vector2.TransformNormal(sourceVector, destinationMatrix);` used for transforming **Velocity vectors**.

Is that true?. Who knows the explanation in detail, please help!

Comment: Have you tried reading the documentation? A quick search reveals that `Transform` is for position vectors and `TransformNormal` is for *normal* vectors.

Comment: what are the _normal vectors_?

Comment: I read the short desc from this: http://xboxforums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/58388/357821.aspx. But not so clear

Comment: You may want to read up on a bit of linear algebra. If you intend on doing game programming, you'll need to know what it is. See [Normal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_%28geometry%29) from Wikipedia (2nd search result on Google).

Comment: A normal vector is a vector with a length of 1 (via Pythagoras' theorem) -- You use them to indicate direction (instead of position, or velocity, etc.).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With transformation, functions will multiply the source vector with the produced matrices.

- `Transform()` is used for vectors representing the positions in 2D or 3D space. This will, in detail, take the Transpose (T operator) of the Invert matrix represents your Coordinate.

In Math: `retVec = T(M ^ -1) x srcVec`.

- `TransformNormal()` used for direction, tangent vectors. This reserves the matrix.

In Math: `retVect = srcVec x M`.

*To transform a vector from one matrix/coordinate to another (say M1 to M2):* **`retVec = Transform by M1 -> then transform by invert of M2`**:

```
        Vector2 retVec = Vector2.Transform(vectorInSource, M1);

        Matrix invertDestMatrix = Matrix.Invert(M2);
        outVect= Vector2.Transform(retVec , invertDestMatrix);
```

Answer (score 5):

The simple answer is that -

`Vector2.Transform()` applies the entire `Matrix` to the vector while

`Vector2.TransformNormal()` only applies the Scale and Rotational parts of the `Matrix` to the vector.